# How to put marker on svg map image using Mapbox?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-marker

I am trying to figure out how to put marker on state map(svg file). State map is divided into counties and I need to put icon on counties based on condition. There are some good example on mapbox site to add markers on map but I am not sure how to load svg map in mapbox and add marker to counties. May be I am asking totally wrong questions. Please guide.

I have seen this example - https://www.inhofe.senate.gov/

I am trying to do same for learning but not sure how to get started using same example. 
Thats the image - https://www.inhofe.senate.gov/assets/images/theme/okstatemap.svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in using a purely SVG map without any [georeferencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georeferencing) or an underlying coordinate system, Mapbox may not be the best tool for your use case. Typically, if you were to use Mapbox to implement a state map displaying county borders accompanied by markers for each county, the workflow would look like:

1. Creating a [GeoJSON](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/geojson/) file containing the data for the county boundary data. (You can consider this [state boundary GeoJSON](https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_110m_admin_1_states_provinces_shp.geojson) from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) as an example.)
2. Adding this GeoJSON data as a [source](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/) to your map.
3. Adding a corresponding [layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/) to visually style the data presented in the aforementioned source.
4. Using a tool such as [Turf.js](https://turfjs.org/)'s [`centroid` method](https://turfjs.org/docs/#centroid) to obtain the center coordinate of each state, and [add a marker](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-a-marker/) for each of these coordinates.

[This example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/polygon-popup-on-click/) from our documentation demonstrates the results of steps 1-3 in practice. This would likely be a better approach than using SVGs if you are interested in using Mapbox in your implementation.

Comment: is it possible that I can show map which cannot be zoom in out or may be static image. Above example looks perfect but only issue is that map can be zoomed in/out.   Can I load svg image here as data source ?  ```map.on('load', function() {
// Add a source for the state polygons.
map.addSource('states', {
'type': 'geojson',
'data':
'https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_110m_admin_1_states_provinces_shp.geojson'
});```